# Fastest way to apply a function returning multiple values on a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe:

```
           pair    price          ts
0       BTCUSDT  4724.89   985446400
1       ETHUSDT   384.79   985446400
2       BTCUSDT  4724.89   985447400
3       ETHUSDT   384.79   985447400
4       BTCUSDT  4724.89   985448400
...         ...      ...         ...
172795  BTCUSDT  4834.91  1071843400
172796  ETHUSDT   388.46  1071844400
172797  BTCUSDT  4834.91  1071844400
172798  ETHUSDT   388.46  1071845400
172799  BTCUSDT  4834.91  1071845400
```

And I would like to use pandas_ta library to apply a predefined set of indicators on the values of every pair in the dataframe.

So far, I have managed to obtain the fastest approach like this:

```py
seconds[['EMA', 'SMA', 'RSI']] = seconds.groupby("pair", group_keys=False, sort=False)["price"].apply(
    lambda x: pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "EMA": ta.ema(x, length=14),
            "SMA": ta.sma(x, length=14),
            "RSI": ta.rsi(x, length=14),
        }
    )
)
```

However, I feel like creating a new Dataframe for each pair, especially when there are more than two, is not really that optimal.

I have also tried returning a tuple like this:

```py
seconds.groupby("pair", group_keys=False, sort=False)["price"].apply(
    lambda x: (
        ta.ema(x, length=14),
        ta.sma(x, length=14),
        ta.rsi(x, length=14),
    )
)
```

But I can't figure out how to append the results from this tuple to my df in an efficient manner. I can notice that every element of the tuple holds all the needed colums to be appended, but don't know how to proceed from here. This seems to be around 30% faster than creating a separate dataframe for each pair.

```
(0             NaN
 2             NaN
 4             NaN
 6             NaN
 8             NaN
            ...   
 172791    4834.91
 172793    4834.91
 172795    4834.91
 172797    4834.91
 172799    4834.91
 Name: EMA_14, Length: 86400, dtype: float64,
 0             NaN
 2             NaN
 4             NaN
 6             NaN
 8             NaN
            ...   
 172791    4834.91
 172793    4834.91
 172795    4834.91
 172797    4834.91
 172799    4834.91
 Name: SMA_14, Length: 86400, dtype: float64,
 0               NaN
 2               NaN
 4               NaN
 6               NaN
 8               NaN
             ...    
 172791    99.993504
 172793    99.993504
 172795    99.993504
 172797    99.993504
 172799    99.993504
 Name: RSI_14, Length: 86400, dtype: float64)
```

Thank you in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pd.concat` to combine the results of your tuple. Just concat all the first elements of the tuple, then all the second elements, and so on. Then add them to the dataframe, each as a new column:

```
your_tuple = seconds.groupby("pair", group_keys=False, sort=False)["price"].apply(
    lambda x: (
        ta.ema(x, length=14),
        ta.sma(x, length=14),
        ta.rsi(x, length=14),
    )
)

columns = ["EMA", "SMA", "RSI"]
for idx, col in enumerate(columns):
    # Grab the "pieces" of each calculation from your_tuple, and concatenate them
    seconds[col] = pd.concat([group_results[idx] for group_results in your_tuple])
```

The series in `your_tuple` have the same index as the dataframe, so pandas unscrambles them in order to match the dataframe index when you do `seconds[col] = pd.concat...`

That being said, according to my tests with some dummy data, this ran just as fast as your initial approach that created the dataframes (which I don't think is bad at all).

If you're looking to make things faster you could also try to replace the `apply` for another method to manipulate groupby objects. From the pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

> While `apply` is a very flexible method, its downside is that using it can be quite a bit slower than using more specific methods like `agg` or `transform`. Pandas offers a wide range of method that will be much faster than using `apply` for their specific purposes, so try to use them before reaching for `apply`.

Another thing you could do is parallelize your operations. Depending on your task, parallelization may not even be worth it, so you'll have to test things for your specific situation. Below is an example on how you could use `multiprocessing` to parallelize the groupby computation:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import pandas_ta as ta

metrics = [ta.ema, ta.sma, ta.rsi]
def calculate_metrics_for_group(group):
    return [metric(group, length=14) for metric in metrics]

grouped = seconds.groupby("pair", group_keys=False, sort=False)["price"]
with Pool(cpu_count()) as pool:
    your_tuple = pool.map(calculate_metrics_for_group, [group for _, group in grouped])

columns = ["EMA", "SMA", "RSI"]
for idx, col in enumerate(columns):
    seconds[col] = pd.concat([group_results[idx] for group_results in your_tuple])
```

Comment: Thank your for your amazing and extensive comment! After I did some verification, it turns out your concat method is around twice (2X) as fast. However, I have encountered a little problem I cannot seem to get past. What if an indicator depends on the values of another one. For example, what if in the list of indicators, I have ta.slope(df['ema'], 28), which depends on the values of the already calculated ema. I cannot return a tuple from the lambda function because slope doesn't know who ema is yet. Do you have a suggestion on how I can do this?

Comment: If you are working with python 3.8+ and really wanna keep the lambda function, you can use the **walrus operator** `:=`. It allows you to assign a variable in the middle of an expression. You replace `ta.ema(x, length=14)` with `ema := ta.ema(x, length=14)` and the result will be returned to the tuple **and** stored in a variable called `ema`. Then you can use `ema` to calculate `ta.slope`. Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/CarlosGDCJ/566fffb945f2bf1e8859f39abe47ba5a). Alternatively you drop the lambda like [this](https://gist.github.com/CarlosGDCJ/3a39f78b72b04956f643db0a44e00890)

Comment: That's an amazing advice, thank you! I didn't really know about the walrus operator. I double checked and it seems like the `pd.DataFrame({})` approach is still a little bit faster compared to concatenating the series for every pair. However, now I'm stuck with another problem. I want to do everything dynamically (with a dynamic list of indicators). I managed to find a way to do slope as `'slope' = ta.slope(ta.ema(x, 14), 28)`, so basically calculating the ta.ema twice, however your walrus operator way is faster, but I cannot seem to implement it into the pd.DataFrame({}), I'll show you below:

Comment: So, basically, it would look [like this](https://gist.github.com/TheWCKD/d5cb8e69ea26b3daaf7c988d1d4cbf45).

But as you can see here, I find a hard way programmatically naming the ema variable to use the walrus operator in order to assign it before setting it as a value to the dictionary key. 

`'ema' : (ema := ta.ema(x, length=14)), 'slope': ta.slope(ema, 28)`

Basically, I can name the dict key by calling indicator.name, but I cannot set the name of the variable from the string denoted by indicator.name. Can you suggest a better approach? Thank you again, you are of great help!

Comment: I don't think dynamically creating variables is the best way to do this. Adding a cache to the calculation of the indicators would probably be a better approach. That way you could call `ta.ema(x, length=14)` with the same x as many times as you want and it will run only once: from the second time onwards it will used the cached result. This way you don't need the walrus at all. You can implement a cache manually with a dictionary or try to use something like [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I managed to get the best time by caching the results in a dict and then returning that dict into a `pd.DataFrame(cached)`